# Why this recursive concat produces: Data too long

Tags: mysql, concatenation, varchar, recursive-query

I have this table on MySQL 8:

```
create table tbl(id varchar(2), val int);
insert into tbl values ('A',  1), ('B',  2), ('C',  3), ('D',  4), ('E',  5);
```

The following query should find out which record sets have values that add up to a value not greater than 6 (without importance of order):

```
with recursive cte(greatest_id, ids, total) as (
    select     id,
               concat(id, ''), 
               val
    from       tbl
    union all
    select     tbl.id,
               concat(cte.ids, tbl.id),
               cte.total + tbl.val
    from       cte 
    inner join tbl 
            on tbl.id > cte.greatest_id
           and cte.total + tbl.val <= 6
) 
select ids, total from cte
```

[Running it](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hKg5xqJsyUoQQaHzXhqh54/0) results in the following error:

> Error: ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: Data too long for column `concat(id, '')` at row 7

**Why does MySQL produce this error?**

For info, the desired output is below:

```
 IDS | TOTAL
 ----+------
 A   |  1
 B   |  2
 C   |  3
 D   |  4
 E   |  5
 AB  |  3
 AC  |  4
 AD  |  5
 AE  |  6
 BC  |  5
 BD  |  6
 ABC |  6
```

I want to know by which (documented?) rule MySQL produces this error here.

By comparison, the query works fine on PostgreSQL and Oracle (using their syntax variation), so I don't really understand *why* MySQL is having a problem with it.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, then your next stop should be to the MySQL site to file a bug report.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A long way down the MySQL 8 CTE [manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) is an example that shows the problem you are having. Basically the problem is that your `ids` column is too narrow for the `ABC` value being assigned to it as it gets its width from the non-recursive part of the CTE (which is effectively the length of `id` i.e. 2 characters). You can solve that problem with a `CAST` to a big enough width to fit all the results e.g.:

```
with recursive cte(greatest_id, ids, total) as (
    select     id,
               CAST(id AS CHAR(5)) AS ids, 
               val
    from       tbl
    union all
    select     tbl.id,
               concat(cte.ids, tbl.id),
               cte.total + tbl.val
    from       cte 
    inner join tbl 
            on tbl.id > cte.greatest_id
           and cte.total + tbl.val <= 6
) 
select ids, total from cte
```

[Update of your demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hKg5xqJsyUoQQaHzXhqh54/2)

Comment: Nice answer! What still surprises me is that it does not depend on the length of the actual string in the non-recursive part of the query, but on the data type, even when a function like `concat` is applied to it. The original query works when the condition is `<= 3`, so recursive results with max 2 letters are still OK.

Comment: @trincot I presume `<= 3` works because you declared `id` as `VARCHAR(2)`, which will fit `AB`. but then that makes me wonder why `<= 6` fails at row 7. I guess the cte is generating rows in a different order than they are eventually output.