# SQLAlchemy basic recursive CTE example - hierarchical tree query

Tags: python, mysql, recursion, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression

I am having trouble understanding how **recursive CTEs** are to implement in SQLAlchemy. Either there are no examples, I dont understand them or could not find them.

I am actually using Django 2.2 with Python 3.7, Conda and SQLAlchemy with MySQL 8. But as far as I understand/have noticed, that does not matter for my problem very much.

I have created an *Adjacent List Model* in MySQL following [this](https://www.tekz.io/blog/mysql-adjacency-list-model-for-hierarchical-data-using-cte/) guide as well as had a look at [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/self_referential.html) manual from SQLAlchemy.
**Questions** are following after the MWE.

My database defintion would be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE events (
 id int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name varchar(255) ,
 parent_id int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
 description varchar(255) DEFAULT=NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES events (id)
);
```

and using this dummy-entries:

```sql
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (1, "root", null);
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (2, "A", 1);
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (3, "B", 1);
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (4, "C", 1);
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (5, "D", 1);
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (6, "A1", 2);
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (7, "A2", 2);
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (8, "B1", 3);
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (9, "B2", 3);
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (10, "D1", 5);
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (11, "A1A", 6);
INSERT INTO events (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (12, "A1B", 6);
```

In Django I have created this model definition to access with SQLAlchemy

```py
class Events(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = Column(INTEGER(10), primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(INTEGER(10), ForeignKey('events.id'))
    name = Column(String(255))
    description = Column(String(255))

    children = relationship('Events')
```

So far simple querys in SQLAlchemy works like a charm. but i fail to understand how to translate `WITH RECURSIVE` and similar requests into SQLAlchemy queries.

Example, asking for 5 columns (last 2 which are altered/created through the recursion) showing the tree and depth of every database entry:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy AS
(
  SELECT id, name, parent_id, 1 AS depth, name AS path
    FROM events
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.id, e.name, e.parent_id, h.depth + 1, CONCAT(h.path, ' > ', e.name)
    FROM hierarchy AS h 
      JOIN events AS e ON h.id = e.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM hierarchy;
```

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/cairabbit/d64fccf7cf2abe180e69c843706f46c7) query example and tried to adapt it as follows (where as `parent` is supposed to represent the `path` above):

```py
hierarchy = self.session.query(
        Events, literal(0).label('level'), null().label('parent')
    ).filter(
        Events.parent_id == null()
    ).cte(name='hierarchy',recursive=True)

h = aliased(hierarchy, 'h')
e = aliased(Events, 'e')

hierarchy = hierarchy.union(
    self.session.query(
        e2, (h.c.level + 1).label('level'), h.c.name                         
    ).filter(
        (e2.parent_id == h.c.id)
    )
)
result = self.session.query(Events, hierarchy.c.level).all()
```

The last line of the above code is issueing an error stating `(1406, "Data too long for column 'parent' at row 1")` as well as the created SQL-Statement:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy(id, parent_id, name, description, level, parent) AS (
 SELECT events.id AS id, events.parent_id AS parent_id, events.name AS name, events.description AS description, %(param_1)s AS level, %(param_2)s AS parent 
 FROM events 
 WHERE events.parent_id IS NULL 
 UNION 
 SELECT e2.id AS e2_id, e2.parent_id AS e2_parent_id, e2.name AS e2_name, e2.description AS e2_description, anon_1.level + %(level_1)s AS level, anon_1.name AS anon_1_name 
 FROM events AS e2, hierarchy AS anon_1 
 WHERE e2.parent_id = anon_1.id
)
SELECT events.id AS events_id, events.parent_id AS events_parent_id, events.name AS events_name, events.description AS events_description, hierarchy.level AS hierarchy_level 
FROM events, hierarchy;
```

**Questions**

1. Does anyone can provide a link where there is a detailed explanation
   on how to translate into an recursive CTE query in SQLAlchemy?
2. What exactly does `.cte(recursiv=True)` in the SQLAlchemy query? `name=hierarchy` is probably setting a specific name which would otherwise be something made up.
3. Why is the error `Data too long...` issued and how could I solve this (the actual output in this question is not important, rather to find out what exactly is too long and where it comes from)?
4. Why is the reference to `c` as a field of `h` e.g. `h.c.name`\ `h.c.level` neccessary and where does it come frome?
5. (How do I use `func.concat` in this query to show the path similar to `CONCAT(h.path, ' > ', e.name)`?)

I can see that this is a somewhat unusual question and I am probably looking at it from a wrong angle, but I spent quite some time on understanding this topic and havent gotten very far.

Any help or advices on how to improve my question are appreciated.

Comment: Your 3rd point is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732559/why-this-recursive-concat-produces-data-too-long. In short, the type of the column "parent" of the CTE is deduced from the non-recursive part of the union, which in your case is `NULL AS parent`, and so its type is `binary(0)`.